# jQuery Ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

here's my function:

```
$(".home .up_0").click(function() {
    $.post("includes/vote.php",   
        {truc : $(this).attr("id")},
        function(data) {
            if(data==1) {
                $(this).parents('.home').find('.score_neutre').append(
                    $(this).parents('.home').find('.score_neutre').val()+1
                );
            } else  {
                alert("Error !");
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

When I click everything works but it doesn't change the `.score_neutre` value (which is 1 and I want it to change to 2).

Comment: you're retrieving a json response and using it as a string.

Comment: Btw json looks like this
{score:12} or {values:{score:12}}, which you would access with
data.score or data.values.score repectively. Your just wanting whatever was passed back don't use json, if you want to use json encapsulate everything in php as an associative array and then use json_encode($array);

Answer (score 3):

You need to test (data.score==1) not data

"score" being the associated array name for the json data you sent in.

Comment: I don't really get it, in my php file i just send back 1 if it works, and 0 if it doesnt. And it works :|

Answer (score 2):

What does your json response look like? You can't compare it like this with a number.

Additionally you are using `append` which most likely is wrong. I guess want you really wanted to do is

```
var ele = $(this).parents('.home').find('.score_neutre');
ele.val(ele.val()+1);
```

Comment: well, append or this doesnt work. I think that it's because it's inside the function(data) that it doesnt work